# Rails 3 with joins among 2 tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, view

I have 2 models, **car** and **registrations**.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Registration
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

In CarsController:

```
def index
  @cars = Car.all
  @cars2 = Car.all(:joins => :Registration)
end
```

In view:

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= car.twitter %></td>
    <td><%= car.facebook %></td>
    <td>
    <% @cars2.Registration.each do |h| %> #here is my problem
      <%= h.email %>
    <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is my statement of cars. I am trying to print for every car owner's email. The email is in table **Registration (model registration)**. I don't know how to make a query to database, that I want to get email from table Registrations, when column registration_id in table **Cars** == id column of table Registrations...

So I would like to ask you, if you have a tip, how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got your associations in capital letters. It should be in small like this

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :registration
end
```

Also you dont have to assign 2 variables in the controller

```
def index
  @cars = Car.includes(:registration)
end
```

and in the view

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= car.twitter %></td>
    <td><%= car.facebook %></td>
    <td>
      <%= car.registration.email %> #here is my problem
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead to fetch the email:

```
<%= car.registration.email %>
```

If you want eager loading, then use the following line in your controller instead:

```
@cars = Car.includes(:registration)
```

There's no need for `@cars2`.

Comment: <%= car.registration.email %> I tried to use, but I got an error: "undefined method `registration' for ..." I have no idea, why I got this error, associations looks right (I think)